# Taking a subset from one dataframe and assigning it across multiple columns in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe (df1) that has information in it that I want to make a subset of and assign it across multiple columns in a new empty dataframe (df2), but I want it to start assigning them at a column that is not the first column. I run it and get no errors, but nothing actually populates df2.

I already have the subset working correctly (called 'subset'). The subset is the correct amount of columns to match up with how many columns are being specified in my code. The name of the columns are already named and specified in some code beforehand. Below is my line of code trying to assign it the new dataframe:

```
 df2.loc[:,['col3','col4','col5','col6','col7','col8','col9','col10','col11','col12']] = subset
```

Like I said before, no error messages. In the end, I just want the data from the subset to actually populate those specific columns in df2.

EDIT: What df1 and df2 look like:

An example of what a subset from df1 looks like:

```
Index     col1     col2     col3     col4     col5     col6     col7     col8     col9     col10
0         blue     OSX      800      800      1.65     Pass    0.597      SH1     0.065    NaN    
1         red      O4M      800      800      1.44     Pass    0.876      SH1     0.054    NaN
2         white    O6I      900      900      1.90     Pass    0.589      SH1     0.043    NaN
```

df2 can look something like the following: 'col3' through 'col12' should be populated with the above data from df1 in the same order it is in above.

```
Index     col1     col2     col3     col4     col5     col6     col7     col8     col9     col10     col11     col12
0         4X7Y     43294
1         6TR2     23804
2         5HJ8     32047
```

Comment: Usually we using update

Comment: Can add an example of df1 and what you want df2 to look like?

Comment: I updated the post with what df1 and df2 can look like, thanks